# VS Code for Typescript - setting target to es6 creates js files which show es6 warnings/problems

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

This is a basic config scenario, I'm sure, but not understanding how to use es6 transpiling on Visual Studio Code for TypeScript.

I've got very simple setup:

```
{  
"compilerOptions": {
    "target":"es6",
    "module":"CommonJS",
    "outDir": "out"
}
```

}

And the compiler seems to be working fine, but the generated js files in my outDir are showing warnings on all ES6 language features like `class`.

How do I set VSCode to know that the files in the output directory are ES6 js and not to show in "problems"?

Here's what's goin on in the editor window:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, VSCode ships with ES6 support out of the box. Did you install a custom extension, e.g. a linter plugin, that might be showing you these errors? A similiar discussion can be found [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/using-es6-in-vs-code-editor/256649). 
If this error is generated by a different plugin, you need to look up how to configure that plugin to validate es6 instead of es5.

Comment: Actually on closer inspection it seems that the compiler is showing warnings for all es6 features that don't exist in ES6.  Is there an easy fix for that?

Comment: @user1023110 Depends on the errors it throws. Need a little more context on this one. But this is most likely a seperate problem to your VSCode showing errors on the JS Files. If you inspect the JS Files by hand, it should be valid ES6 (as Typescript would not generate invalid ES6, even it gives you a warning).

Comment: Well, I'm not sure.  My code actually run, have thoroughly tested with Jasmine.  It's just all the ES6 features show yellow squigglys and the problems pane listing 61 problems which aren't really poroblems.  Annoying mainly.  adding a screenshot to the  question

Comment: Turns out that somehow when I installed it, I somehow installed JSHint.  I disabled that and all the problems disappeared.  Thanks for the pointer.